# How To Pass Information From Barcode Scanner Into Specific Textbox Only In VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, barcode

Hy ! I'm developing an inventory and sales project using VB.NET 2008, and I'm using a barcode scanner

there isn't a problem with the barcode reader, but, i want to know, can i place the information from barcode reader into a specific textbox ?

example :

in the program, i have a textbox named txtbarcode. if i want to place the information from barcode reading only into txtbarcode, how to do it ? and if i get my focus into another components (e.g : if i have my focus in txtpay), then i'm doing a scan, how to place the information into txtbarcode ?

it's so frustating, because when i focused into another textboxes or another components beside the txtbarcode, it would stop debugging..

thx a lot !

Comment: Why just not made logic like this, if TXTBARCODE = vbempty, then txtpay.enabled = false

Comment: for some reaseon, i cant do that, because I will pass the data from txtbarcode to another Data grid view.. the only thing i want is how to pass the data from barcode reading, only to 1 specific textbox